# Need to assign two lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Can I have two lists as values for each key in a dictionary?

So, whenever I send the key I will get the two lists of values returned: (list1)(list2)

Thanks

Comment: like this ?  `{'a': (list1, list2)}`

Comment: Can you include your attempt so we can diagnose what went wrong please?

Comment: To be super picky, no you can't have two lists as the value.  You can have one list (or a tuple) as the value, that contains two lists.

Comment: This is more or less the scenario
...dynamic generation of listType1....once ready I want to assign it to the corresponding key
destination_by_type_copy[z].append(listType1)


...dynamic generation of listType2....once ready I want to assign it to the corresponding key
destination_by_type_copy[z].append(listType2)

Finally I want to reach this:

{'a': [(listType1), (listType2)]
 'b': [(listType1), (listType2)]
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
list1 = (1,2,3)
list2 = (4,5,6)
_dict = {
    "a": [list1, list2]
}
print(_dict)
# {'a': [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]}
```

**Edit:**
To address your question about adding a list to the key, just append it like so:

```py
list1 = (1,2,3)
list2 = (4,5,6)
_dict = {"a": []}

_dict["a"].append(list1)
print(_dict)
# {'a': [(1, 2, 3)]}

_dict["a"].append(list2)
print(_dict)
# {'a': [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]}

'''Alternatively if you are wanting to create a new key and assign a list to it you could do something like the below:'''
list3 = (7,8,9)
_dict["b"] = [list3]
print(_dict)
# {'a': [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], 'b': [(7, 8, 9)]}
```

Comment: Exactly.  My problem is that list1 is dynamically generated and I need to assign it to a key.  After some processing, the second list has be assigned to key.  The assignment is failing

Comment: @Rafael I updated the answer to show appending lists to the key
@FreddyMcloughlan good point, have updated it to `_dict`

Comment: @Rafael great! Please accept this as the answer if your issue is resolved :)